# Firefox v67 Private Browsing with geckodriver does not always enable addons

Tags: python, firefox-addon, geckodriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

The newest Firefox version 67 has private browsing add-ons disabled.  These can be added by following this guide. https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/extensions-private-browsing

The issue is that even using that guide the add-ons are not consistently enabled under the geckodriver.

This was functioning in Firefox v66 without issue.

1. I have run an instance with the default firefox profile (Profile0 from profile.ini) with two add-ons (coil and LastPass).  I see the addons popup for about 2 seconds and then disappear.
2. I have manually enabled them inside the private browser by going to about: addons.  It appears that if they are already enabled in the browser for private browser use and are not visible in private browsing changing permissions to disallow still enables them in private browsing, then allowing them keeps them enabled.  Very strange.
3. I uninstalled an addon closed all browsers, started the script again and it worked the first time.  Then on the second run, it was back to the 2 seconds enabled then disappear mode as mentioned above.
4. I've checked the temp profile created under temp when geckodriver copies the profile for consumption.  The add-ons are included.
5. Manually opening up a private browser shows two add-ons so it appears specific to geckodriver + firefox v67.  However, the private browser doesn't have me logged in on my addons.

```py
        def get_firefox_profile_dir(self):
        from pathlib import Path
        self.gecko_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)

        if sys.platform in ['linux', 'linux2']:
            import subprocess
            self.ff_gecko = Path(self.gecko_path + '/geckodriver')

            bits = 'uname -m'
            ver_32_64 = subprocess.getstatusoutput(bits)

            cmd = "ls -d /home/$USER/.mozilla/firefox/*.default/"
            fp = subprocess.Popen([cmd], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
            FF_PRF_DIR = fp.communicate()[0][0:-2]
            FF_PRF_DIR_DEFAULT = str(FF_PRF_DIR, 'utf-8')

            ff_ext_path = os.path.join(FF_PRF_DIR_DEFAULT, 'extensions')
            self.ff_coil_loc = os.path.join(ff_ext_path, self.ff_coil_extId)
            ff_coil_enabled = os.path.exists(self.ff_coil_loc)
            if ff_coil_enabled:
                if 'x86_64' in ver_32_64:
                    if not self.ff_gecko.is_file():
                        import wget
                        self.gecko_targz = 'geckodriver-v0.24.0-linux64.tar.gz'
                        wget.download(self.gecko_source_linux64, self.gecko_path)
                        self.file_unzip_tar(self.gecko_path + '/' + self.gecko_targz)
                        os.remove(self.gecko_path  + '/' + self.gecko_targz)
                    if self.ff_gecko.is_file():
                            self.data_path = FF_PRF_DIR_DEFAULT
                            self.gecko = self.ff_gecko
                            return
                if 'i368' in ver_32_64:
                    if not self.ff_gecko.is_file():
                        import wget
                        self.gecko_targz = 'geckodriver-v0.24.0-linux32.tar.gz'
                        wget.download(self.gecko_source_linux32, self.gecko_path)
                        self.file_unzip_tar(self.gecko_path + '/' + self.gecko_targz)
                        os.remove(self.gecko_path + '/' + self.gecko_targz)
                    if self.ff_gecko.is_file():
                            self.data_path = FF_PRF_DIR_DEFAULT
                            self.gecko = self.ff_gecko
                            return
        elif sys.platform == 'win32' or 'nt':
            from pathlib import Path
            self.gecko = self.gecko_path + "\geckodriver.exe"
            mozilla_profile = os.path.join(os.getenv('APPDATA'), r'Mozilla\Firefox')
            mozilla_profile_ini = os.path.join(mozilla_profile, r'profiles.ini')
            profile = configparser.ConfigParser()
            profile.read(mozilla_profile_ini)

            FF_PRF_DIR_DEFAULT = os.path.normpath(os.path.join(mozilla_profile, profile.get('Profile0', 'Path')))
            ff_ext_path = os.path.join(FF_PRF_DIR_DEFAULT, 'extensions')
            self.ff_coil_loc = os.path.join(ff_ext_path, self.ff_coil_extId)
            ff_coil_enabled = os.path.exists(self.ff_coil_loc)

            if ff_coil_enabled:
                ff_gecko = Path(self.gecko)
                if ff_gecko.is_file():

                    self.data_path = FF_PRF_DIR_DEFAULT
                    return
                else:
                    import wget
                    wget.download(self.gecko_source_win64)
                    self.file_zunip('geckodriver-v0.24.0-win64.zip')
                    if ff_gecko.is_file():
                        os.remove('geckodriver-v0.24.0-win64.zip')
                        self.data_path = FF_PRF_DIR_DEFAULT

                        return
self.get_firefox_profile_dir()
            self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=self.options, firefox_profile=self.data_path, executable_path=self.gecko)
            self.driver.get(self.url)  # OPEN URL
```

I expect the FF addons to be enabled as they have been manually permitted from the browser and that they will be logged in as they are in normal mode.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the core issue was related to the upgrade to v67 and some unknown items in the profile became broken.  A profile reset fixed the issue.

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/refresh-firefox-reset-add-ons-and-settings

UPDATE: After futher testing I see that it shows short term stability and that extensions are hit and miss (more miss) when loading dynamically.   In other words after profile reset addons work the first few times and then they do not load anymore with selenium